# Videojs-vr failed to load videos

Tags: javascript, laravel

Good morning,

I'm trying to set up a small website that allows you to view 360 videos for a project. I based it on a friend's laravel template that works very well but when I try to run the video the browser console gives me this error: [image]

I have searched the internet but have not been able to find the solution to my problem

here is the code I made :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Visite virtuelle</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body class="antialiased" style="background-color: #ebedf0">
<div style="width: 100%; height: 90vh; display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <div style="margin: 2rem auto;">
        <img width="300px" src="images/logo_dahouse.png" alt="Dahouse logo">
    </div>

    <video style="width: 100%; height: 100%" id="videojs-vr-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls playsinline>
        <source src="https://visites.dahouse.fr/videos/5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<script src="js/videojs.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/videojs-vr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(window, videojs) {
        let player = window.player = videojs('videojs-vr-player');
        player.mediainfo = player.mediainfo || {};
        player.mediainfo.projection = '360';

        let vr = window.vr = player.vr({projection: 'AUTO', debug: true, forceCardboard: false});
    }(window, window.videojs));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```